# Issue accessing data from the Twitter API in Linux - keep getting curl: no url specified?

Tags: linux, curl, twitter, debian, tweepy

I'm trying to learn how to use the Twitter API to access tweets in the Linux terminal. I typed this in:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <BEARER TOKEN>" "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/20"
```

Of course, I replaced the `<BEARER TOKEN>` bit with my bearer token. But when I put this into the linux terminal I get this error:

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to specify the GET method (GET is default), and in theory no reason to put the URL in quotation marks.

Can you try this (works for me on Ubuntu 20.04):

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <BEARERTOKEN>" https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/20`

Are you sure you are using "flat" quotation marks, and have not accidentally pasted in "smart" quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this but I still have the same problem and most of the time I was getting the same errors. I repeatedly typed in the same line with slight variations and the closets I got was it trying to retrieve the tweet but then printing 'anauthorized' despite the fact that my bearer token should work...

Comment: Is your app part of a project that has access to the Twitter API v2?

Comment: Yes. I believe I have access to v2 since this app is part of a project.